# Tsql query to find equal row values along columns

Tags: t-sql

I've this table

```
col 1   col 2   col 3   ....    col N
-------------------------------------
1       A       B               fooa        
10      A       foo             cc
4       A       B               fooa
```

it is possible with a tsql query to return only one row with a value only where the values are ALL the same?

```
col 1   col 2   col 3   ....    col N
-------------------------------------
--      A       --              --
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT
     CASE WHEN COUNT(col1) = COUNT(*) AND MIN(col1) = MAX(col1) THEN MIN(col1) END AS col1,
     CASE WHEN COUNT(col2) = COUNT(*) AND MIN(col2) = MAX(col2) THEN MIN(col2) END AS col2,
     ...
FROM yourtable
```

You have to allow for NULLs in the column:

- COUNT(*) counts them
- COUNT(col1) doesn't count them

That is, a columns with a mix of As and NULLs isn't one value. MIN and MAX would both give A because they ignore NULLs.

Edit:

- removed DISTINCT to get counts the same for NULL check
- added MIN/MAX check (as per Mark Byers deleted answer) to check uniqueness